# Что делает конструкция вида ptr = *(void**)ptr где ptr есть void*?

Tags: c++, указатели, преобразование, malloc

Читаю [данную](https://habrahabr.ru/post/148657/) статью, и не могу понять некоторые приёмы. Если кто сможет - пожалуйста расстолкуйте построково что происходит, например здесь:

```
void FormatNewPage() {
    void* tmp = GetPage();                   // получаем адрес начала блоков памяти
    head = tmp;                              // голову на начало блока памяти
    for(size_t i = 0; i < count-1; i++) {
        void* next = (char*)tmp + BlockSize; // получаем адрес следующего блока.
        *(void**)tmp = next;                 // ?? эта манипуляция мне не понятна
        tmp = next;                          // в "текущем" блоке указываем адрес следующего свободного блока
    }
     *(void**)tmp = NULL;                    // последний блок ни на что не указывает - терминируем.
}
```

Общая идея конечно же понятна - идет "разметка" памяти, и используя свойства указателей делают связи - т.е. можно сказать получаю односвязный список на указателей массиве.

Но совершенно не понятно зачем в коде идет такое приведение *(void**), ведь тип и так void*.

Как я понимаю, в результате такого приведения *(void**)tmp - компилятор на tmp смотрит как на разыменованный указатель типа void* - фактически, с моими текущими знаниями - мне кажется это вообще ничего не должно менять. Но Если произвести такой простой эксперимент (g++, linux 64bit)

```
char arr[]={'a','b','c','d','\0'};
void * vptr = new char[1024*2];
std::cout << vptr << '\n';            // 0x9c9010
std::cout << (void**)vptr << '\n';    // 0x9c9010
std::cout << (void*****)vptr << '\n'; // 0x9c9010
std::cout << *(void**)&vptr << '\n';  // 0x9c9010
std::cout << *(void**)vptr << '\n';   // 0  -- почему так ?
memcpy((char*)vptr,arr,sizeof(arr));  //
std::cout << *(void**)vptr << '\n';   // 0x64636261  -- почему так ?
```

Становится видно что *(void**)tmp каким-то образом меняет адрес. Как, к сожалению, не могу найти информацию. Если кто знает объясните, или хотя бы дайте линки что-почитать.

Изучая код из статьи, по ф-ии

```
void* AllocBlock() {
    if (!head) FormatNewPage();
    void* tmp = head;
    head = *(void**)head;
    return tmp;
}
```

Можно сделать вывод что *(void**)head; делает какой-то инкремент адреса указателя, но на моём эксперименте данный инкремент получается очень огромным - и вроде бы значительно выходит за область 1024*2 по адресной арифметике.

Да и почему-то ни в одной статье найти не могу, и в тех книгах которые прочитал (хотя их было и не так много конечно) не было такого приёма прохода по адресам как *(void**) (если это конечно вообще используется для какого-то прохода явно или косвенно)

В общем не понимаю.
Благодарю за уделённое время.

Comment: ** - это указатель на указатель. То есть то, что находится по адресу из tmp, тоже трактуется как адрес и уже по этому адресу ищется значение.

Comment: Smithson, теперь все стало понятно. Сам чето не допёр. Спасибо :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос решен, спасибо пользователю [Smithson](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/190021/smithson)

> ** - это указатель на указатель. То есть то, что находится по адресу из tmp, тоже трактуется как адрес и уже по этому адресу ищется значение

Answer (score 0):

Первая `*` - это разыменование указателя, но `void*` разыменовывать нельзя хотя бы потому, что компилятор не в курсе, какого размера там данные лежат. Значит его надо привести к чему-то, что компилятор знает. `void**` говорит, что указатель указывает на тип `void*`, разыменовывая его мы получаем ссылку на `void*`, которой можем присвоить другой указатель в качестве значения.